# I wonder when replace 0 on a Series(or dataframe), will False also be replaced?

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder if I replace all the integer `0` in a data frame, will `False` also be replaced? I have tried on my MacBook, and it does not being replaced, but one of my friends say his being replaced. I wonder this depends on what machine you use?

Comment: Chances are that it is not machine dependant, however can you post a minimal working example of the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether False will be replaced depends on the dtype of the series:

```
In [12]: pd.Series([0, 1]).replace(0, 99)
Out[12]: 
0    99
1     1
dtype: int64

In [13]: pd.Series([0.0, 1.0]).replace(0, 99)
Out[13]: 
0    99.0
1     1.0
dtype: float64

In [14]: pd.Series([False, True]).replace(0, 99)
Out[14]: 
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool

In [15]: pd.Series([0, 0.0, False, 1.0]).replace(0, 99)
Out[15]: 
0    99.0
1    99.0
2    99.0
3     1.0
dtype: float64
```

If it's not being replaced, your series probably has dtype=bool, and so pandas has decided to pay attention to the type difference.  If your series has dtype=object, it's being treated as a collection of Python-level objects (which it basically is), and since False == 0 == 0.0, all three get replaced.